# Changing background color on input focus with css alone

Tags: html, css, focus

Am trying to change the background color of an input holder once the input is clicked i used these

```
<div class="name"> <input type="text" class="input-name"></div>
```

CSS

```
.input-name:focus + .name{
background:#f00;
}
```

this is how it is normally 
[image]

this is what i want on focus 
[image]

but it wont Work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot select a parent element with CSS.

However. you can fake something similar with a box shadow

```css
body {
    margin: 25px; /* not required */
}

.input-name:focus {
    box-shadow:0 0 0 10px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
    <input type="text" class="input-name" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo-class `:has(child)`
so:

```
.name:has(.input-name:focus-visible) {
     background:#f00;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't select a parent with CSS.

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

This will have to be done via script.

```
(function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('input-name');
    if( !(inputs && inputs.length) ) return;

    function toggleRed(elem) {
        elem.classList.toggle('red');
    }

    for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var input = inputs[i];

        // focus
        input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
             toggleRed(this.parentElement);
        });

        // blur
        input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
             toggleRed(this.parentElement);
        });
    }
})();
```

Check this for a demo

http://jsfiddle.net/andyw_/6ec1efs2/1/

Comment: how do i add more class to it am trying this   var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('input-name', 'input-email', 'input-pass');

Comment: Ideally, you'd use a class for those elements that are meant to have the same effect i.e. `class="js-redhover"`. If you really need to select multiple classes, you would simply select the other classes with `document.getElementsByClassName` and concatenate the results together https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: sorry didnt help can u make some changes for me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/doiks14/6ec1efs2/2/ - simply introduced a new class to assign to all the elements I want to attach the effect to

Answer (score 1):

While the exact thing you want can't be done, @Paulie_D 's answer was the closest with pure css.

To do **exactly** what you wanted you would need to use javascript because, as aforementioned, you can't select a parent element.

Here's the javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("name").style.background = "red";
```

}

And the HTML:

```
<div id="name>
<input type="text" id="input" onfocus="myFunction()">
```